# Segmentation Fault on thread handler

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, pthreads, chatbot

My Chatbot polling feature is not working properly, 
I'm getting segmentation error on a thread handler, i used gdb to see more stuff and here there is what i got:

```
Thread 4 "St3veB0t" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff67c2700 (LWP 5957)]
0x0000555555557243 in poll_handler ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000555555557243 in poll_handler ()
#1  0x00007ffff7bbd6db in start_thread (arg=0x7ffff67c2700)
    at pthread_create.c:463
#2  0x00007ffff78e688f in clone ()
    at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95
```

The function `poll_handler()` is this:

```
void * poll_handler(void * args)
{
    FILE * fp;
    struct VoteData  vote;
    struct PollHandlerData * data = (struct PollHandlerData *)args;
    int res;
    char * string = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER);


    sleep(60);
    *data->status = 0;    
    *data->vote_count = 0;

    if(!(fp = fopen("polls/votes.txt", "r")))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError in reading file\n");
         if(!(fp = fopen("polls/votes.txt", "w+")))
         {
            fprintf(stderr, "\nError in creating file\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
         }
    }

    vote = GetMostVote(fp);

    strcpy(string, "PRIVMSG #st3ver0nix : Polling terminated, the majority voted: ");
    strcat(string, vote.word);
    strcat(string, "\r\n");

     do{
        res = write(data->sock, string, strlen(string));
    }while(res < strlen(string));

    fclose(fp);
    free(string);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

The function that creates the thread is this:

```
void CreatePoll(int sock, char * message, char * poll_name, int * status, int * vote_count)
{
    pthread_t tid;
    struct PollHandlerData * data = (struct PollHandlerData *)malloc(sizeof(struct PollHandlerData));
    char * name = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*MAX_BUFFER);


    GetPollName(message, name);
    sscanf(name, "%s", poll_name);

    data->sock = sock;
    data->status = status;
    sscanf(poll_name, "%s", data->name);

    pthread_create(&tid, NULL, poll_handler, (void *)data);
    pthread_detach(tid);

    free(name);
}
```

The structures `PollHandlerData` and `VoteData` have this form:

```
struct PollHandlerData
{
    int sock;
    char name[128];
    int * status;
    int * vote_count;
};

struct VoteData
{
    char word[128];
    int freq;
};
```

I really don't know what's wrong in my code. I'm using POSIX pthreads.
Pls let me know if you need more information about the code.

Comment: What is `PollHandlerData`? How is it defined? The statements `*data->status = 0;` and `*data->vote_count = 0;` looks suspicious. So does your two `sscanf` calls in `CreatePoll`. And why do you allocate memory for `name` dynamically?

Comment: Probably `*data->status = 0;` should be `data->status = 0;`.  Likewise `*data->vote_count = 0;` should be `data->vote_count = 0;`

Comment: And in C you [should not cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/) (or any function returning `void *`, as well as `void *` arguments).

Comment: Lastly, if you build with debug information (using the `-g` flag when building the source) then you will get proper line-number information in your debugger call-stack.

Comment: There is no option `-g` in gdb...

Comment: The int variables passed to the function `poll_handler` are declared outside the brackets.

Comment: Can you please a buildable code?  It's hard to diagnose it without seeing the whole code.

Comment: Please try to create a [mcve] to show us. This needs to show us how you call your `CreatePoll` function. And (again) please build with debug information enabled so that you know *where* the crash happens in your code when you catch it in the debugger. That is actually very crucial information.

Answer (score 1):

As per the observation in `poll_handler()` thread assignment is done for the `vote_count` is making this crash:

```
*data->vote_count = 0;
```

In function `CreatePoll()` before creating the thread `vote_count` pointer inside the `data` variable is not allocated or not pointing to any valid pointer since only malloc is done to variable `data` and it will have any garbage value. So it is getting crashed in the `poll_handler()` while accessing invalid pointer.

note: `vote_count` will have a garbage value, if this is a valid pointer for the process then this may not make process crash.

Comment: It's not a guaranteed crash. It will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) though, and is the *probable* cause of the crash.

Comment: Yes this is undefined behavior, based on the value that is present in vote_count crash may not happen also, but most probably this will lead to crash as the value will not be pointing to a valid address witch is allocated for the running process by memory management unit.